# making base class functions invisible to client

Tags: c++, derived-class

I want to make all functions in my base class invisible to my client, only accessible through my derived class.

Is there a way to do this in C++?

Thanks!

Comment: are you familiar with protected keyword?

Comment: Make them `protected`. By `client` did you mean the objects of base class?

Comment: Unclear. What do you mean by "invisible" and "client"?

Comment: Public inheritance is a contract. You are not allowed to renege on a contract.

Comment: Get [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1). It will tell you all about it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways one is

**Using Protected Keyword**

```
class A{
    protected:
        void f(){
            std::cout << "F" << std::endl;s
        }
};
class B:public A{
    // access f() here...
};
```

Any derived class can access `f()` function from A class.

Second way: 
**Making B class friend class of A.**

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
    private:
        void f(){
            std::cout << "F" << std::endl;
        }
    friend class B;
};

class B:public A{
    A obj;
    public:
        void accessF(){
            obj.f();
        }
};
int main(){
    B obj;
    obj.accessF();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Need a forward declaration of `B` in order for `A` to `friend` it.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't think so, I have tested it. Can you explain why it required?

Comment: My apologies. Jumped the gun. Same namespace exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use access-specifier (if base class is not under your control):

```
class A
{  public:
    void f() {}
    void h() {}
};
class B: private A  // all members of A are private
{ public:
    void g()
    { f();
    }
    using A::h;     // adjust access
};

int main()
{ A a;
  a.f();
  B b;
  b.g();
  b.h();
  b.f();  // error: 'void A::f()' is inaccessible
}
```